# Angular 17.0.6 issue with ng-bootstrap 16 heeeeeelp

Tags: dependencies, npm-install, ng-bootstrap, conflicting-libraries, angular17

I am trying to install ng-bootstrap 16 in the cli and I have already try to add directly to the dependecies
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap":"16.0.0" and then execute "npm install" but was useless because always give me the next error:

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: marktec@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found:
> @angular/core@17.0.6 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core npm ERR!
> peer @angular/core@"17.0.6" from @angular/animations@17.0.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/animations npm ERR!     peerOptional
> @angular/animations@"17.0.6" from @angular/platform-browser@17.0.6 npm
> ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser npm ERR!       peer
> @angular/platform-browser@"17.0.6" from @angular/forms@17.0.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^17.0.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!       3 more
> (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
> npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^17.0.0" from the root project npm
> ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.0.6" from @angular/common@17.0.6 npm
> ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!     peer
> @angular/common@"17.0.6" from @angular/forms@17.0.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^17.0.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"17.0.6" from
> @angular/platform-browser@17.0.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser npm ERR!       peer
> @angular/platform-browser@"17.0.6" from @angular/forms@17.0.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^17.0.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!       3 more
> (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
> npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,
> @angular/router, the root project) npm ERR!   6 more
> (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not
> resolve dependency: npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"16.0.0" from
> the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:
> @angular/core@17.1.1 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core npm ERR!
> peer @angular/core@"17.1.1" from @angular/forms@17.1.1 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular/forms npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from
> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap npm ERR!
> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"16.0.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

as I said I have already try to clean the cache and to write directly into the dependencies and then execute the npm install command, but did not work I only wanna use the typeahead in my project :(

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

- ng add @angular/localize
- npm i @popperjs/core
- npm i  @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
- ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap